# TinkerCAD Digital Logic

Tags: digital-logic, switches, logic-gates, breadboard, cad

[image]

Everything here seems to be right, like the gates and resistors, but the gate seems to be the issue; the LED is off when the switch is on. What is the issue? I have also included the schematic.

[image]

Comment: The schematic does not match the circuit and that circuit keeps the LED off. Should the the schematic and circuit match? If yes, then that is the issue.

Comment: How does it not match?

Comment: Look at the gate where the only LED is. Does the gate get the inputs from the switches? No. In the schematics, yes. Also, it does not match because there are 3 LEDs in the schematics and only 1 in the board. They are completely different circuits and what the board does or should do is a mystery.

Comment: @Justme Yes, that's true, there is one LED, when there should be three. I tried only doing one LED first, but it failed. How would I do three?

Comment: By connecting the wires to chips in the TinkerCad design as per the pin numbers and connections shown in the schematics. But your design has XOR and two AND chips. The schematics have one XOR, one AND and one OR chip.

Comment: The board has a 74HC86 and two 74HC08s, with outputs of the 74HC86 and one 74HC08 feeding the inputs of the second 74HC08.  The schematic has a 74LS86, a 74LS32 and a 74LS08, with the switches connected directly to inputs of all three ICs.

Comment: Sorry, I just started all this last week. How would I directly connect the switch to the three ICs?

Comment: @user367142: your schematic shows S1 connected to pin 1 on all three ICs, but the board just has S1 connected to pin 13 of the middle IC. The horizontal connections on the board below the switches connect pins 1 and 2 of the first IC to Ground, not to the switch outputs.

Comment: @PeterBennett Do you mean the lower right of the gate or the power rail?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if the schematic should match the TinkerCad drawing, they don't.

The TinkerCad design will always keep LED off by design. The AND gate driving the LED has always one input 0 so no matter what the first AND gate outputs to the second AND gate based on switches, the output to LED will always be off.

Comment: Thank you! What should I change?

Comment: You might want to start by double checking if the buttons and LED connect to even the same AND chip you want to be using like in the schematics.Then move the incorrect connections to correct pins.

Comment: @user367142: Decide what you want to build, draw the schematic, then wire the breadboard to match the schematic.

Comment: That's the problem here; I'm not sure how to, this was my best guess.

Comment: @user367142 Print the design and schematic out, take pen and paper, maybe a cup of coffee, and verify that each pin on each chip connects to wherever it needs to. If it doesn't, fix the TinkerCad wiring so that they do match. The schematic and TinkerCad design should be just two different-looking views of same circuit.

Comment: Alright, thanks!