# TinkerCAD Digital Logic LED

Tags: led, digital-logic, switches, logic-gates, cad

I finished building this circuit in TinkerCAD, but for some reason the AND gate won't behave like it's supposed to. Shouldn't the LED turn ON when both 1 and 2 are ON? Instead, it turns ON when both 1 and 2 are OFF. Can anyone tell me what's the issue here? What should I change? Everything else seems to be working.

[image]

[image]

I also included the schematic for this circuit. I realize that in the schematic it uses LS gates, but in TinkerCAD there are no LS gates, so I used HC gates instead, the only available gate type available on TinkerCAD. Is there any difference?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TinkerCAD Digital Logic Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705282/tinkercad-digital-logic-question) <-- in other words, why are you asking the same question again instead of modifying your original.

Comment: @Andyaka I modifying my answer accordingly; they're completely different now.

Answer (score 1):

When the switches are on, the gate inputs will be Low, as the switches connect points A and B to Ground.

When the switches are off, the pull-up resistors will hold the gate in puts at a High logic level.

With its inputs both Low, U1A's output will also be Low, so its LED will not light.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So from my understanding, my circuit is correct?